# How do I make a custom form errors section in my Django template?

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

In my Django template I can show errors using this syntax `{{ form.errors }}`.
But that evaluates to this html syntax in my template:

```html
<ul class="errorlist">
   <li>password
      <ul class="errorlist">
         <li>Ensure this value has at least 10 characters (it has 2).</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>confirm_password
      <ul class="errorlist">
         <li>Ensure this value has at least 10 characters (it has 2).</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>first_name
      <ul class="errorlist">
         <li>Ensure this value has at least 2 characters (it has 1).</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>last_name
      <ul class="errorlist">
         <li>Ensure this value has at least 2 characters (it has 1).</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is not the html syntax I want. I actually want to wrap them in my own elements.
For example

```html
{%if form.errors %}
   <section class="errors-container">
      {% for err in form.errors %}
         <p>{{err.field_name}}</p>
         <div>
            {{err.actual_error_for_field_name}}
         </div>
      {% endfor %}
   </section>
{%endif%}
```

That is the layout I want.
I even tried passing an errors variable to the context dictionary in my view.

```py
def user_register(request):
    errors = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.cleaned_data['password'] == form.cleaned_data['confirm_password']:
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                new_user = Person.objects.create_user(username=cd['username'], email=cd['email'],
                                                      password=cd['password'],
                                                      first_name=cd['first_name'], last_name=cd['last_name'])
                messages.success(request, f'You are successfully registered as {new_user.username}!')
                return redirect("profile", new_user.id)
        for i in form.errors:
            errors[i] = form.errors[i]
        print(errors)
    else:
        form = PersonRegisterForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': 'Register',
        'errors': errors
    }
    return render(request, 'index/register.html', context)
```

But that didn't turn out to be very effective since i could not loop over the `errors` dictionary in my template using Jinja2 syntax, since `{% for a, b in errors.items() %}` would give me this error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'errors.items()'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close, when something is callable, Django will call it automatically. So you can iterate over the errors:

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <section class="errors-container">
    {% for f, es in form.errors.items %}
        {% for e in es %}
             <p>{{ f }}</p>
             <div>
                {{ e }}
             </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </section>
{% endif %}
```

The `{% for e in es %}` is necessary, since errors maps the fieldname on a *list* of errors, and thus we need to iterate over the list to iterate over *individual* errors.